# Scope query in a many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I created 2 models, "Post" and "Category". This is a many to many relationship, works great.

My tables are the following :

- alex_blog_posts : where posts are stored with columns like "title", "published" etc...
- alex_blog_categories : where categories are stored with columns like "title", "parent_id" etc...
- alex_blog_posts_categories : where the relation is stored between posts and categories with columns "post_id", "category_id"

Let's assume I want to filter all posts that are associated to a category with name : "Category 1"

```
public function scopeFilterCategory($query) {
    $query->join(????); // My problem is to replace the ???
    $query->where('title', '=', 'Category 1');
    return $query;
}
```

I'm not familiar enought with october and laravel yet and I'm stuck here. Probably very simple for laravel expert but I need a concrete example of something working cause all things I tried failed :/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

laravel have the "whereHas":

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

On the post model you need the write this query:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas($relationName, function ($query) {
     $query->where('title', =, 'Category 1');
})->get();
```

$relationName - should be the name of the function that define the relation in your model (etc: 'categories')

Answer (score 0):

##### For Laravel

There is a good answer on Laracasts

[Scope for many to many relation](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/scope-for-belongstomany-relation?page=1&replyId=84148)

The following is an improved version.

Assume we have `authors` & `articles` many-to-many relation (with a pivot `authors_articles`);

Assume we have `belongsToMany` relation defined in both models;

```php
// in Article model

public function scopeFromAuthor($query, $authorId)
{
    return $query->whereHas('authors', function ($query) use ($authorId) {
        $query->where('authors_articles.author_id', '$authorId');
    });
}
```