# laravel querying many to many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, **Service** and **Category**. They are related with a many-to-many relationship like so:

```
Service.php

public function categories()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
}
```

```
Category.php

public function services()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service')->withTimestamps();
}
```

And of course they're joined by a pivot table:

```
category_service

  - category_id
  - service_id
  - created_at
  - updated_at
```

I'd like to use local scope to filter service result based on IDs of categories. I've done the following:

```
Service.php

public function scopeFilter($query, $category_ids)
{
    $services = Service::whereHas('categories', function (Builder $query) use ($category_ids) {
        $query->whereIn('category_id', $category_ids)->get();
    });

    return $services;
}
```

But I'm getting a `Column not found` error, specifically:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'services.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` inner join `category_service` on `categories`.`id` = `category_service`.`category_id` where `services`.`id` = `category_service`.`service_id` and `category_id` in (1, 2))
```

**1 and 2** are the category IDs I pass.

I wrote the function based on the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979922/laravel-query-many-to-many) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365305/scope-query-in-a-many-to-many-relationship).

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message show that your query is begin with `categories` and without join `services`.

So put the `->get()` outside the closure.

```php
public function scopeFilter($query, $category_ids)
{
    $services = Service::whereHas('categories', function (Builder $query) use ($category_ids) {
        $query->whereIn('category_id', $category_ids);
    })->get();

    return $services;
}
```